# Do OpenID Connect Providers encrypt then sign their JWTs?

Tags: salesforce, jwt, google-openid, openid-connect

My team is making an existing product an OpenID Connect RP (relying party) and are using connect2id's [Nimbus JOSE + JWT library](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt). That library supports signed and encrypted JWTs, but only signed first, then encrypted. They [have their reasons](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/signed-and-encrypted-jwt) for not supporting encrypt-then-sign, but our concern is that some of the OPs we need to interact with may do encrypt-then-sign.

We are initially targeting Salesforce and Google. I have been unable to determine from their documentation whether, when acting as OpenID Connect Providers, Salesforce and Google use sign-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-sign.

Can anyone point me to pages where this is documented for these OPs? Or is it a non-issue because no one uses encrypt-then-sign? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When/if encryption is used, Connect OPs will always sign and then encrypt, if they are following the specification. [Section 2 of OpenID Connect Core](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) says, "If the ID Token is encrypted, it MUST be signed then encrypted". [Section 16.14, Signing and Encryption Order](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SigningOrder) says the same thing in a little more detail.

Comment: Fantastic. I totally missed this. Thanks very much.

Comment: Signature after encryption is dangerous as the signature could be removed and replace by another. That is why it is mandatory to sign first then encrypt.

Comment: I would be remiss if I didn't also politely suggest taking a look at jose4j for JOSE/JWT processing :) The JwtConsumer and JwtConsumerBuilder should be particularly useful for the OpenID Connect RP role. Some examples at https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples